# How can i pinch zoom webview inside scrollview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I want to zoom `WebView` inside `ScrollView`.
I applied these codes to webview, but zoom function doesn't work. because scrollview, parent of webview, scrolls itself.

```
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

how can i pinch zoom in my situation? please help me !

Answer (score -3):

I wouldn't put a Webview inside of a ScrollView, that's just asking for user errors. Put the WebView outside of the ScrollView, and you'll be good. If you really want to put the webview inside of a ScrollView, android can't tell between WebView touch events and ScrollView touch events.